# conduit to connect panels outside

Tags: conduit

I am connecting a 200 amp meter/distribution panel to a 100 amp RV panel (both mounted on the same post outside). Can I connect the two with metal, pvc, or the flexible non metal or metal conduit to run my wires? They will only be about 6 inches apart, back to back. So, it would work best to come out side knockouts, because the RV panel is only 9inches wide and i would not be able to access the back knockout. Please advise.
Thanks
Dean

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124827/discussion-on-question-by-dean-conduit-to-connect-panels-outside).

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I would affix a chunk of marine plywood to the pole, prime it, paint it with exterior paint, and attach the RV panel to that.  That will give you more freedom to position it for a "back to back", "out the bottom of the RV panel and then in the back of the main" with a single bevel 90, or down, over and up with two 90s.

Given the very short distance, the cost of wire is negligible, so I would use #3 copper.  I'm not a huge fan of copper for feeder, but it's the most compact, so it'll fit in the smallest conduit.

---

Here's the thing about those "50/30/20" RV stands.  Generally, you're expected to install one of those per RV site.  And then, the RV is expected to use the **one** socket that is compatible with its power.

You keep talking like using all three of them at the same time, *you're not **required** to provision for that*.  You only need to provision for the largest socket available to any given site, and you ignore all the smaller sockets.

If you follow the "One 50/30/20 panel per site", then it's pretty simple.  You calculate based on 50A/12,000 watts *per panel/site*, and then apply the favorable derate that Ed Beal mentioned from 551.73.

- 90% if 2 sites (so 90A for two 50/30/20 RV stands)
- 80% if 3 sites (so 120A for three 50/30/20 RV stands)
- 75% for 4 sites
- 65% for 5 sites
- 60% for 6 sites
- 55% for 7-9 sites (thus you can support *seven* 50A sites from 200A service)

So again, **you don't have to provision more sockets than you have RV sites**.  You just count your RV sites and provision *that many* sockets, largest first.

And follow what Ed Beal says about how 50A RVs take **a lot** more power than 30A RVs.  That is  because 50A RVs take 240V power, not 120V.  They take over triple the power of a 30A.

- 50A/240V sockets are 12,000 watts
- 30A/120V sockets are 3,600 watts
- 20A/120V sockets are 2,400 watts
- By the way, tent sites follow a special rule and you must only figure them for 600 watts.

And then apply the derate as Ed says.

Like I say, given your 100A provisioning, I would just go ahead and install two 50/30/20 RV subpanels at wherever you expect will be most useful.   Because the subpanels are good for 100A busing, you don't actually need to give them separate breakers - you can simply daisy chain from one subpanel to the next.  But the wire needs to be 100A.

Does it matter how many sites you support with **two 50/30/20 RV stands**?  Actually it doesn't -- no combination will exceed 100A.

- 2 sites: 12,000 x 2 = 24,000 W x 90% derate = 90A
- 3 sites: 12,000 x 2 + 3600 = 27,600 W x 80% derate = 92A
- 4 sites: 12,000 x 2 + 3600 x 2 = 31,200 W x 75% derate = 97.5A
- 5 sites: 12,000 x 2 + 3600 x 2 + 2400 = 33,600W x 65% derate = 91A
- 6 sites: 12,000 x 2 + 3600 x 2 + 2400 x 2 = 36,000 W x 60% derate = 90A

Comment: / ed beal - Gentlemen. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Ed says use a 70amp. Is that what you both recommend? I was going to mount both panels on a piece of plywood side by side but decided to just go with the post so I don't have to worry about the plywood decaying. The Post I am getting will out live me. It will not be a problem mounting them back to back on post. Because of the two panel size differences, I will be able to come out the bottom back of Main panel and into the bottom side of the RV panel Both already have knockouts in those locations. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Dean the 50/30/20 panel can only draw 80 amps there is 1 240v load the other 2 are 120v and are each put on 1 leg so the maximum load would be 80 amps with all 3 maxed out, code requires the load to be balanced one leg would have a max of 80 the other 70 and that is IF the 3 were drawing maximum (they never do).

Now if we look at code NEC 551.73 the feeder shall be based on 12000 per site with 50 amps, 3600 va per site with 30 amp and 2400 per site with 20 amp.

That’s all well and good 50/30/20 but now if you start with multiple units table 551.73.A allows the feeder to be have a derate 3 sites is a .80
18000x .80=14400 /240= 60 amp

So by code if you were planning for 3 sites on this feeder you could legally feed this with a 60 amp breaker and wiring and be fine as I said above you never draw full capability and yes I have wired several MH parks.

As I suggested if you want some over kill go 80 amps on your feeder breaker,
If you want a little buffer above the absolute minimum go 70 amps
And the minimum is 60 amps for these 3 sites.

if in Arizona where you will need lots of cooling go with 80 again that is the max the 3 sites can draw as 2 are 120v and they will be on opposite legs.

70 amps provides a nice point between the max draw and minimum if just the 2 main sites are in use a 60 amp feeder would be code compliant.

2 sites is a derate of .90 and the calculated load of 58.5 rounds up to 60 amps.
Again 70 would provide a nice cushion between the minimum allowed by code and the maximum that could be drawn 80.

Putting in a 100 amp breaker and feeder is a waste unless you already have the breaker. If you like to go big go 80 that is more than needed and totally future proof. If you want to save a little go 70 still going to work for most areas most of the year. High heat areas when multiple AC’s are the worst case I have seen.

Comment: There may be some confusion on what I am doing. It may not matter in the end but let me make it clear. I have a 200 amp meter/panel combo with 200amp breaker. I also have a 100 amp RV panel that has 50amp, 30amp, 20amp breakers & receptacles. They are both being mounted on one post. There is only ONE RV site. But because I have multiple receptacles it will allow me to hookup more then one RV to the same panel if I ever wanted to. I want to make sure the breaker I install will support that. What size breaker should I use?

Comment: Dean code will allow a (50 if only 1 site ) 60 as my answer suggests because of the plan for multiples, you can not draw more than 80 from all 3 receptacles running at 100% it is very clear what you have and want to do. code will allow as small as 60 because you plan on multiple loads but as large as you want.  anything more than 80 is a waste so you have a choice 60,70,80,90,100. 
I personally would go 70 unless in a hot location like Arizona then I would use 80 amp.

Comment: Thank you Ed, maybe I am confused...lol. But I am clear now. Minimum 60 and 100 if I want to waste my money.

Comment: That’s what I would say you could put in the max of a 100 amp breaker because the RV pedestal is 100 amp but you have to have a breaker to protect the smaller system if the feeder panel was 100 amp you could go with out a second breaker but then the wires are much larger and harder to work with 80 is the max that can be drawn with the 3 sites so I would not go above that.

Comment: The RV panel does have it's on breakers on each receptacle, so the smaller systems are each completed protected. The Breaker in 200 amp panel is just to provide adequate power to support the potential draw .

Comment: But the RV panel is only rated for 100 amp so it requires protection of a 100 amp or less breaker. If the RV panel was rated for 200 amp you would have to pull 3/0 wire (if the RV pedestal were rated for 75 deg).  You will need to check I know some of the 50’s I installed were 60 degree rated, it depends on the brand and that may be a wire size jump also.

Comment: ok to avoid any issue I am just going to install a 100amp breaker to feed my RV panel. Rv panel is factory wired from breakers to receptacles. All I need to do is feed it with power. I will use #3 copper off the 100amp breaker in main panel to RV panel lugs. Sound good?

Comment: If the panel is 75 degree rated you can use #3 copper if it is 60 degree rated #1 copper, with a 100 amp rating it should be 75 deg rated. The 100a breaker is fine as I said in the answer it’s just a waste since you can never draw more than 80.

Comment: I ended up getting #3 copper (all 4 wires). I had to order it. Then I saw someone said #3 #3 #3 # 5. I know larger is ok rather then smaller, but will # 3 fit a 100amp panel ground bar? I was going to check when I get home

Comment: If it doesn't fit and it may not you may have to purchase a “chair lug” and bolt the ground to the case, this can be part of the problem with oversized conductors # 6 is normally the max size needed (I don’t remember seeing any ufer grounds at RV parks all driven rods).

Comment: -Ok, or I will have to purchase # 5. I was told I did not need a grounding rod for the RV panel.

Comment: Dean if your 4 wire goes back to the service there are exceptions for rods in that case but you are going a bit overboard so I expected it.

Comment: I considered using a rod for RV panel, but L&I said I only need two for the main meter/panel. 
Oh and #3 copper ground wire fits the ground lug in my RV panel